# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined in angular 2 after build

Tags: angular

I am using google map autocomplete and [NgUIMap](https://rawgit.com/ng2-ui/map/master/app/index.html#/places-auto-complete). When I run it on the local machine it runs perfectly fine. After building the angular 2 project for production, it shows the following error

[image]

Please refer the details error info as shown below:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
    at PlacesAutoComplete.initialize (places-auto-complete.js:17)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (places-auto-complete.js:24)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.js:245)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at FirstSubscriber._emitFinal (first.js:135)
    at FirstSubscriber._emit (first.js:118)
    at FirstSubscriber._next (first.js:97)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at ReplaySubject.Array.concat.ReplaySubject._subscribe (ReplaySubject.js:55)
    at ReplaySubject.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:57)
    at ReplaySubject.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:97)
    at ReplaySubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:45)
    at FirstOperator.call (first.js:70)
    at PlacesAutoComplete.initialize (places-auto-complete.js:17)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (places-auto-complete.js:24)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.js:245)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at FirstSubscriber._emitFinal (first.js:135)
    at FirstSubscriber._emit (first.js:118)
    at FirstSubscriber._next (first.js:97)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at ReplaySubject.Array.concat.ReplaySubject._subscribe (ReplaySubject.js:55)
    at ReplaySubject.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:57)
    at ReplaySubject.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:97)
    at ReplaySubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:45)
    at FirstOperator.call (first.js:70)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:710) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:681) [angular]
    at :8000/static/polyfills.bundle.js:3412:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4140) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:591) [<root>]
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464) [<root>]
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1084
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1144
next @ core.es5.js:4778
schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3851
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:236
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3837
NgZone.triggerError @ core.es5.js:4209
onHandleError @ core.es5.js:4170
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:369
Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:141
_loop_1 @ zone.js:602
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:611
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:464
```

A portion of the code is given below.

```
initialized(autocomplete: any) {
    this.autocomplete = autocomplete;
}

placeChanged(place) {
    this.address = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        this.address[addressType] = place.address_components[i].long_name;
    }
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: how are you building? angular cli?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Hello! sorry for late reply.

Comment: i am building  - npm build --prod

Answer (score 0):

using `ChangeDetectorRef` service in `Constructor`, we can access the `Viewchild` reference element in view Template:

```
Constructor(private ref : ChangeDetectorRef){
}
//call detectChanges function before where to ViewChild  element Native Element attribute

this.ref.detectChanges();
```